# Convert Lambda Expression Group By to LINQ Version

Tags: c#, .net, linq

please consider this code:

```
var result = data
        .GroupBy(a => groupA.Contains(a.Group) ? "A" : 
                      groupB.Contains(a.Group) ? "B" : 
                      "N/a")
        .Select(a => new
        {
            KEY = a.Key,
            VALUE = a.Count()
        });
```

can any one help how to convert `GroupBy` to `LINQ` version?

thanks

---

**Edit 1)**

I want this style:

```
from a in ....
group a by ....
select ...
```

Comment: sry didnt understand.is it not linq already?

Comment: Do you mean to "Query Expression"? if that's the case, just get LINQPad and go banananananananna's.
http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: is there any reason you want to go back to the old style.you should be sticking to fluent style as it makes your code look lot better

Comment: I write All Queries in my project in old style and I want to know what is equivalent of that query in old styke

Comment: Please see my suggestion in my first comment. You won't be unhappy, promise :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try somethink like this but I would stick to what you have if it works

```
 var result=   from p in data
    group p by new 
   { Criterion = p.Contains(p.Group) ? "A" : p.Contains(p.Group) ? "B" : "N/a" } 
    into g  select new {KEY = g.Key, VALUE = g.Count()};
```

Comment: thanks it works.just anther little question.In first `Lambda Expression` query when I use `KEY = g.Key` and bind my query to gridview it show `A` and `B` but in your code when I bind the result to gridview it doesnot show KEY.How I can show that column without using `KEYA = g.Key.A ,KEYB = g.Key.B`.I want just one column

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
        var result = from a in data
                     group a by groupA.Contains(a.Group)
                                    ? "A"
                                    : groupB.Contains(a.Group)
                                          ? "B"
                                          : "N/a"
                     into d
                     select new
                                {
                                    KEY = d.Key,
                                    VALUE = d.Count()
                                };
```